# JMH 1.27 fails to work with long arguments list in JVM

Tags: java, jmh

I tried to use JMH 1.25 in my project where list of dependencies was very huge.

```
Options opts = new OptionsBuilder().include(".*")
        .warmupIterations(10)
        .measurementIterations(10)
        .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
        .timeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS).jvmArgs("-server")
        .forks(1).resultFormat(ResultFormatType.TEXT).build();

new Runner(opts).run();
```

However I got an error:

```
<failed to invoke the VM, caught IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe": 
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long>
```

So I followed an advice and used new JVM argument jmh.separateClasspathJAR:

```
.jvmArgs("-Djmh.separateClasspathJAR=true")
```

However I got another error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'other' has different root
```

So I upgraded to JMH 1.27 but the exception still remained:

```
<failed to invoke the VM, caught IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe": 
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long>
```

JMH log:

```
# JMH version: 1.27
# VM version: JDK 15, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 15+36-1562
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe
# VM options: -Djmh.separateClasspathJAR=true
# JMH blackhole mode: full blackhole + dont-inline hint
```

Comment: did you consider filling a defect at github jmh repo?

Comment: @Eugene Not yet. JMH bug tracker is not on the jmh github, but at separate location: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/ Not sure if I have permissions to create issues there. Anyway I hoped that this question would be noticed by JMH authors.

Comment: I still got `CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long` error with version 1.26. And got `'error' has different root` at 1.25 or 1.24

Comment: Did you try to run with the compiled JAR?